# Adding a template part as part of a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, templates, conditional-content

I am using "Ultimate Member" plugin to allow users to register because I want some content to be restricted for not signed-in users. According to their documentation, there are a few shortcodes for that and I'm trying to sue one in a template like this:

```
<?php
    $out_content = get_template_part( 'templates/template-parts/loggedout', 'content' );
    do_shortcode("[um_loggedout] {$out_content} [/um_loggedout]");
?>

<?php
    $in_content = get_template_part( 'templates/template-parts/loggedout', 'content' );
    do_shortcode("[um_loggedin] {$in_content} [/um_loggedin]");
?>
```

Actually, both template parts are output this way, is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_template_part` doesn't return its value, it outputs it, which is how it would normally be used. Think of it this way, how would it know wether to `echo` the template or return it?

So instead, we use output buffers to catch the output and flush it to a variable, e.g.:

```php
ob_start( );
echo "test";
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

#### Further Notes

- Avoid embedding variables directly in PHP strings like this: `"variable: {$variable} "` instead use concatenation: `" variable:".$variable`. It's not possible to sanitise of escape if you embed in a string directly
- Shortcodes are a fancy way of calling a function, since you're in PHP rather than post content, why not skip the middle man and call the function directly?
- You've closed a PHP tag, then reopened it but there's nothing between the tags, save yourself the effort of typing it out and keep all your PHP together in one block
- Since you're only checking if a user is logged in or out, there's no need for shortcodes and output buffers at all, just use `is_user_logged_in()` with an `if (...) { .... }` statement.

Comment: This was a case of overthinking things. Like you said, is_user_logged_in() worked perfectly fine. Thanks!